# Strange issue with displaying cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have UITableView with methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

So, the problem is that Xcode runs at first

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

which returns me 1.
Later it runs `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` which also returns me 1.

BUT I do not know why after these 2 methods it does not run `cellForRowAt` method and does not display any row on my UITableView.

I do not know what happens there and why this happens.
Have you met such problem and could you please help me to fix it?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController, let fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
        if !searchController.isActive {
            print("numberOfRowsInSection fetchedObjects.count - \(fetchedObjects.count)")
            return fetchedObjects.count
        } else {
            if let results = filteredResult[searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] {
            print("numberOfRowsInSection results.count - \(results.count)")
                return results.count
            }
        }
    }
    print("numberOfRowsInSection - 0")
    return 0
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let frc = fetchedResultsController, frc.fetchedObjects?.count != 0 {      
        print("numberOfSections - 1")                              
        return 1
    } else {
        print("numberOfSections - 0")            
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Check count for number of row and sections in these methods. Anyone of those will be zero (0)   or Your table may not be visible (visible area of screen)

Comment: @Krunal yes. It sounds logical. But I checked that many times! I do not get 0. I see only the header of my UITableView, but rows field is empty

Comment: Have you checked by adding a print statement in `cellForRowAt` method, if it runs or not, just to be sure?

Comment: @Krunal I've putt `tableView.reloadData()` in my `viewWillAppear` and I debugged there, checked values of `(lldb) po tableView.numberOfSections` >> `1`.
`(lldb) po tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)` >> `1`
So, rows must be there!

Comment: @Krunal Okay, I'll do that, but I just noticed this `Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo (null)`
Is it helpful?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 No. I did not get in logs my prints. It does not call `cellForRowAt` at all

Comment: As Krunal suggested please share your code to get the solution instantly

Comment: @Krunal I shared my methods. If you need anything - just ask

Comment: @Krunal I got this: `numberOfSections - 1`, `numberOfSections - 1` and 
`numberOfRowsInSection fetchedObjects.count - 1`

Comment: As you said, a strange issue.. Share a project with copy/sample for this code that is only way to find out error cause.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that your cell has height `0`. When this happens, `cellForRowAt` won't be called at all, even if the other methods return a non zero `section`/`row` count.

My guess as to why this is happening is that you may be using auto layout for your cell, but your constraints don't allow the cell to figure out its own height. You may be using auto layout unknowingly, since on iOS 11, it's now the default. If you are using storyboards you can set the height for the cell prototype on the attributes inspector, instead of checking the `automatic` box. Alternatively, you can set it in code with `tableView.rowHeight` or by implementing `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`